# ¿Como puedo arrancar mi app en CRA y que esta abra con el navegador Edge?

Tags: reactjs, script, edge

tengo un proyecto en CRA, estoy usando win10 y mi navegador por defecto es Firefox. Me gustaria que al arrancar mi proyecto éste arrancara con el navegador Microsoft Edge y no con Firefox.
He usado una linea como esta en el script del package.json para abrir con Chrome y funciona:

```
"start:react": "cross-env BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start",
```

Pero si coloco esto para Edge no me funciona:

```
"start:react": "cross-env BROWSER=edge react-scripts start",
```

¿Conocen alguna forma de hacerlo que funcione?

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto:
El detalle estaba en que yo colocaba la linea del script de la siguiente forma usando el nombre del navegador **"edge"**:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = edge react-scripts start",
```

Pero el nombre del navegador es **"msedge"**. De esta forma la linea del script queda así:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = msedge react-scripts start",
```

De esta manera funciona correctamente.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada pasadas unas horas.